# How do I move alphanet blockchain data to new partition?

Tags: alphanet, config

I checked this post [Moving chain data to a new hard drive](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/moving-chain-data-to-a-new-hard-drive), but I was unable to do them. I couldn't create the symlink, because I don't know where the data is.

- Where is the blockchain data that I can create the link to?
- How is that command written?

I also tried the commands listed here: https://tezos.gitlab.io/tezos/introduction/howto.html, but I think those are extra steps that I don't need. I already have a running alphanet, so shouldn't I already have a config file? Where is it? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the chain data is stored in the ("hidden") directory located in `~/.tezos-node`.

If you want to avoid using a config file, you can use the proposed "symlink" method. Otherwise, you can simply move the data directory:

- stop your node,
- move the data directory wherever you want (`mv ~/.tezos-node /path/to/somewhere`),
- run your node using the `--data-dir /path/to/somewhere` optional argument to specify a custom data directory location.

You should consider using the config file as it avoid using many option when running your node and eases the deployment.